# is it possible to raise error in ffmpeg commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I am trying to create pan effect but with some images it is giving an error `Conversion failed!` and when that error occurs then i want to run commands in exception.

code is below-

```
        try:
            cmd = "ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i " + combined_url + " -ss 0 -t 3 " + " -filter_complex" + " '[0:v]scale=w=-2:h=3*720,crop=w=3*1280/1.4:h=3*720/1.4:y=(in_h-out_h)-t*(in_h-out_h)/5:x=t*(in_w-out_w)/5,scale=w=1280:h=720' " + " -c:v h264 -crf 18 -preset veryfast " + vid_out
            os.system(cmd)

        except:
            con_img = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/images/" + filename + "." + image_url.split(".")[-1])
            cmd1 = "ffmpeg -i " + combined_url + " -vf scale=1280:720 " + con_img
            os.system(cmd1)
            cmd = "ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i " + combined_url + " -ss 0 -t 3 " + " -filter_complex" + " '[0:v]scale=w=-2:h=3*720,crop=w=3*1280/1.4:h=3*720/1.4:y=(in_h-out_h)-t*(in_h-out_h)/5:x=t*(in_w-out_w)/5,scale=w=1280:h=720' " + " -c:v h264 -crf 18 -preset veryfast " + vid_out
            os.system(cmd)
```

so, I want if any error occurs in try command then command in except should run.

I have posted a solution in answers.

Comment: You need to specify the Exception that is raised right after `except`. Otherwise, it won't run (the default Exception is `ValueError`, which is what your code is trying to catch)

Comment: What's the full error traceback?

Comment: if you `except Exception as err:` you get the behavior you seek. Warning though catching all exceptions like this is typically considered bad form and can mask bugs and can put your application into unanticipated states. If there is a common exception being thrown and you see it in your stack trace, I would catch it rather than everything.

Comment: @JonSG  thanks guys for your response. I have found the solution though. I have updated it on my post.

Comment: @chemicalwill I have updated solution on post

Comment: @12944qwerty I have updated solution on post.

Comment: I might `raise UserWarning` then `except UserWarning` in that case rather than `raise Exception`

Comment: @JonSG Okay, I would try that for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my question is-

```
    try:
        cmd = "ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i " + files4 + " -ss 0 -t 3 " + " -filter_complex" + " '[0:v]scale=w=-2:h=3*720, crop=w=3*1280/{}:h=3*720/{}:y=(in_h-out_h)-t*(in_h-out_h)/5:x=(in_w-out_w)-t*(in_w-out_w)/5, scale=w=1280:h=720' ".format(1.4,1.4) + " -c:v h264 -crf 18 -preset veryfast " + files5
        if os.system(cmd)!=0:
            raise UserWarning
    except UserWarning:
        files7 = "path"
        cmd1 = "ffmpeg -i " + files4 + " -vf scale=1280:720 " + files7
        os.system(cmd1)
        cmd = "ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i " + files7 + " -ss 0 -t 3 " + " -filter_complex" + " '[0:v]scale=w=-2:h=3*720,crop=w=3*1280/1.4:h=3*720/1.4:y=(in_h-out_h)-t*(in_h-out_h)/5:x=t*(in_w-out_w)/5,scale=w=1280:h=720' " + " -c:v h264 -crf 18 -preset veryfast " + files5
        os.system(cmd)
```